# Div jumps out of space on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fixed ! (answer below)

I have this animated banner which i include on all the pages. Unfortunately it jumps out of his space when the browser window gets resized.

You can check it out here: http://www.paparashie.nl/woonkans/

Here's the code:

```
<style> 

#banner{
    position: relative;
    margin-left:-1000px;
    height:195px;
    width:1000px;
    z-index:1;
}   

#banner img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
#banner img.active{z-index:4}
```

```
<script>
    function cycleImages() {
    var $active = $('#banner .active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#banner img:first');
    $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function () { //fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
    });
}
    $(document).ready(function () {
     // run every 2s
     setInterval('cycleImages()', 2000);
 })
</script>


<div id="banner">
<img src="img/logo.png" style="float:left"  />
<img class="active" src="img/banner.png" alt="Banner image" />
<img src="img/banner2.png" alt="Banner image" />    
<img src="img/banner3.png" alt="Banner image" />    
<img src="img/banner4.png" alt="Banner image" />
</div>
```

---

So, i changed the margin to   margin:0 auto . Next mistake was that i had the include code-line wrapped in a , this messed up everything so i simply removed it.

Noob problems ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to build a responsive website... 
Try this as slider:

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Its easy to use and its responsive.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I started building this thing with the another slider (Liquid Slider) but as more as i was working on it, the more complicated it got. So i decided building one on my own. First time jQuery but it's not that bad, is it ?

Comment: Its not! You are caching your queries, which is good practice. Some much more advance programmers arent doing that... so good work! Keep working on your slider, learning by doing its the best way!